# QGIS3 Python setLayers for map item in layout

Tags: qgis-3

I have a layout with four maps over four pages in QGIS 3.4. I am building a python plugin to simplify map production for non GIS users. I am having difficulty defining the layers I want in each map item, as each map item will have slightly different layers. So far I have the code (I have left out some code above that loads a layout template and yes I have no doubt my code has some ineffeciencies :p ):

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layout = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("test")
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)

layerList = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()

extent = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
extent.grow(0.7)

map1 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
layers =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
zoning = layers.values(map_layer1)
map1.setLayers(zoning)
map1.setFrameEnabled(True)
map1.setRect(QRectF(20, 20, 20, 100))
map1.setExtent(extent)
layout.addLayoutItem(map1)
```

I have tried a few options but keep getting the same error:

*NameError: name 'map_layer1' is not defined*

So, I'm not really sure where to go from here. I am just testing with two layers in the  map canvas at this point, map layer 1 and map layer 2.

Comment: The error is clear, `map_layer1` is not defined, add where you define it. If you want set all layer in this map need this `map1.setLayers(layers)`

Comment: Yes. I think I was not clear enough with my question. Defining the layer is where I am having problems. I've not done this before and the methods I've tried have failed. My last attempt was to use:                                                  layer =QgsVectorLayer('path', 'name', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

Comment: It appears that QgsMapLayerREgistry however is no longer for QGIS3.

Comment: QgsMapLayerRegistry. Its functionality has been moved to QgsProject.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding this:

```
vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("map_layer1")[0]
```